# Why this code giving me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,a;
    int* p;
    p=&a;
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        *(p+i)=i;
        printf("%d\n",*(p+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to assign numbers from 0 to 10 in a sequence memory location without using an array.

Comment: You're writing out of bounds. `a` only has room for one value, so `*(p+i)` is out of bounds when `i > 0`.

Comment: You can't do this without an array or dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: If you could write more than one `int` into a single `int` storage, that would save a ***huge*** amount of memory usage. Unfortunately, though, you can't do that.

Comment: Process attempting to access memory which is not owned by it will lead to UB.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write to memory that it does not have permission to access.

The variable a is a local variable in the `main` function, and it is stored on the stack. The pointer `p` is initialized to point to the address of `a`. The code then attempts to write to the memory addresses starting at `p` and going up to `p+10`. However, these memory addresses are not part of the memory that has been allocated for the program to use, and so the program receives a segmentation fault when it tries to write to them.

To fix this issue, you can either change the loop condition to a smaller value, or you can allocate memory dynamically using `malloc` or `calloc`, and assign the pointer to the returned address. This will allow you to write to the allocated memory without causing a segmentation fault.

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int* p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 11);  // Allocate memory for 10 integers
    if (p == NULL) {  // Check for allocation failure
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        *(p+i)=i;
        printf("%d\n",*(p+i));
    }
    free(p);  // Free the allocated memory when you are done with it
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is only an integer. not an array.

you need to declare it differently:

```
 int i, a[10];
```

Comment: OP is aware of array, mentioned in question - _......memory location without using an array_

Answer (score -1):

You can not. Memory of int is 4 bytes and you can store **only single** number in that memory.

for int: -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647

for unsigned int: 0 to 4, 294, 967 295

There are other types you can use with different sizes, but if you want to put different numbers into one variable you need to use array.
`int arr[10];`
`arr[0] = 0;`
`arr[1] = 5;`
something like this.

Comment: *"int is 4 bytes"* is not guaranteed (and therefore the ranges you posted are also not guaranteed). It may be more or less (e.g.: It used to be 16bit on most PCs back in the 90s)